# Java stream sorting a List of String as numbers problem

Tags: java, sorting, java-stream

I have an issue sorting a list of QuestionNumbers as Strings.

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("12.2", "12.1", "12.3", "12.4", "12.5", "12.10");

List<String> sortedList = list.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

When printed out sortedList I get:

```
12.1
12.10
12.2
12.3
12.4
12.5
```

I tried the following but getting a multi points errors.  Please help

```
.sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(question ->(Double.parseDouble(question.getQuestionNumber()))  ))
```

Comment: In what order do you expect 12.1 and 12.10 to be sorted?

Comment: I would like sortedList to be: 12.1, 12.2, 12.3, 12.4. 12.5, 12.10

Comment: @HoangNguyen Since you've changed the Math here, you might want to introduce a variation using `String` length. Try comparing string length and then its Double value.

Comment: You get compiler errors, because a `String` doesn’t have a method `getQuestionNumber()`. The naming of the lambda parameter suggests that you are suddenly expecting your string to be of type `Question`. Or you just did a copy&paste without even trying to understand the code’s meaning. Besides that, do you understand that `12.1` and `12.10` are the same numeric value, so comparing them as double doesn’t produce your desired order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was written in comments: you can combine two `Comparator` first is by length, then by `String` value.

```java
list.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator
            .comparing(String::length)
            .thenComparing(String::compareTo))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

#### UPDATE

As it was written by Holger there are some problems with above approach.
It can be rewrite as below:

```java
list.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing((String s) -> s.split("\\."),
        Comparator
            .comparing((String[] a) -> Integer.parseInt(a[0]))
            .thenComparingInt((a) -> a.length > 1 ? Integer.parseInt(a[1]) : 0))
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But it looks more complicated and it's doing more or less the same what was proposed by [VGR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60199335/11733759). So in the end you can write it like this:

```java
list.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Runtime.Version::parse))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: So `2.1` is smaller than `1.10`?

Comment: Thank you.  The UPDATE version works as I am not using Java 9 yet so Version won't work.  Thank you all for this.

Answer (score 3):

String.compareTo compares Strings lexicographically.  Digits are just characters in such a comparison, no different from letters or punctuation or emojis.

You need a Comparator which recognizes the *nn*.*nn* format.  You could write a new Comparator, but a more manageable approach is to have a class which parses such strings.

If you’re using Java 9 or later, you’re in luck:  There’s already such a class.  That class is [Runtime.Version](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runtime.Version.html).

So you can sort your strings by comparing their respective Runtime.Version equivalents, then converting the sorted objects back to strings:

```
List<String> sortedList =
    list.stream().map(Runtime.Version::parse).sorted()
    .map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Or `list.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Runtime.Version::parse)) .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @Holger I considered that, but it would mean executing Runtime.Version.parse twice for each and every comparison, which is considerably more than just once per element.  I went with something that was a better fit for the general case, even though there wouldn’t be much difference for the six strings in the given example.

Comment: It’s hard to compare the parsing costs with the costs of an additional `toString()` operation. Of course, for a sufficiently large list, the time complexity of the sorting operation will suggest that two linear operations are preferable. But it’s unlikely that the OP will ever have to deal with large enough lists…

Answer (score 0):

You're sorting string, your result is correct if you want to sort a string. But in your case, you should convert it to float, double, Double or BigDecimal...

Try this code:

```
List list = Arrays.asList("12.2", "12.1", "12.3", "12.4", "12.5", "12.10");

List sortedList = list.stream()**.map(Double::valueOf)**.sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Converting this value, you will have the correct order for numbers.

Comment: I am still getting [12.1, 12.1, 12.2, 12.3, 12.4, 12.5]

Comment: I would like sortedList to be: 12.1, 12.2, 12.3, 12.4. 12.5, 12.10